# PHP - Mysql prepare won't execute

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i am trying to create mysql entries with a tool called editable grid (http://www.editablegrid.net/en/). I just added 2 textfields on the code.. but it seems like the mysql prepare code dont like what i am doing.

Thats the php code:

```
    require_once('config.php');         

// Database connection                                   
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$mysqli->real_connect($config['db_host'],$config['db_user'],$config['db_password'],$config['db_name']); 

// Get all parameter provided by the javascript
$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
$firstname = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['firstname']));
$uid = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['uid']));
$show = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['show']));
$tablename = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['tablename']));

$return=false;
if ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$tablename."  (name, firstname, uid, show) VALUES (  ?, ?, ?, ? )")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $firstname, $uid, $show);
    $return = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}             
$mysqli->close();        

echo $return ? "ok" : "error";
```

and here the html Code:

```
 <div id="addform" style="height:210px;">

            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" />
            </div>

             <div class="row">
                <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname" />
            </div>
             <div class="row">
                 <input type="text" id="uid" name="uid" placeholder="uid" />
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" id="show" name="show" placeholder="show" /> 
                </div>

            <div class="row tright">
              <a id="addbutton" class="button green" ><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Apply</a>
              <a id="cancelbutton" class="button delete">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

they both are connected together with javascript and this worked. I just added 2 textfields. Ist there an error in the Php code. Arent i allowed to use 4 values throughout the prepare statement?

Comment: Don't escape and parameterize, just parameterize. Don't escape the table name, use a white list of allowed names. When you execute what happens, do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

The code seem correct but variable tablename is not defined, so add more textfield to html

```
<div class="row">
<input type="text" id="tablename" name="tablename" placeholder="input table name" />
</div>
```

Or set table name in php

```
$tablename = 'table name here';
```

Comment: i checked that.. does not effect the script. Still not working